# How can I set the total number of data items in my grid using a function?

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've tried various ways to set the total number of records in the `Kendo-UI Web Grid`, without success.

I'm kind of lost on where I spend the amount processed in ajax, already assigns the total value in the schema for 4 to see if it happens more paging did not work, just shows the two records and it shows that there are more pages.

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful!

```js
...
transport: {
    read: function (option) {
       $.ajax({
       url: '<?=$view->encode('ctrl.php?turma=lista_turma');?>',
       data:{
          skip: option.data.skip,
          take: option.data.take,
          pageSize: option.data.pageSize,
          page: option.data.page,
          sorting: JSON.stringify(option.data.sort),
          filter: JSON.stringify(option.data.filter)
       },
       success: function (result) {
           option.success(JSON.parse(result));
       },
       error: function (result) {
          alert(result);
       }
    },
    schema: {
       data: 'data',
       total: function (data) {
           return 4;
       },
       /*total: function (result) {
          alert('aqui');
          result = result.d || result;
          return 4;
       },*/
       model: { id: "id_turma" },
          fields: {
             id_turma: { validation: { required: true } },
             nome_turma: { validation: { required: true } },
             sigla_turma: { validation: { required: true, max:12 } }
          }
          }
       },
       pageable: true,
       serverPaging: true,
       serverFiltering: true,
       serverSorting: true,
       batch: true,
       pageSize: 2
});
```

Comment: You should try rephrasing this here: "So I'm kind of lost on where I spend the amount processed in ajax, already assigns the total value in the schema for 4 to see if it happens more paging did not work, just shows the two records and it shows that there are more pages .". It's really hard to understand what you did, what you expected to happen and what did happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with all those "eval" statements in your code. This looks like you're overcomplicating things a lot.

If you do server-side paging, the total should be returned from the server since the client typically doesn't know how many more records there are. If your response contains a property "total", then this should work:

```
schema: {
    total: "total" // total is returned in the "total" field of the response
}
```

or this, if you want to use a function:

```
schema: {
    total: function(response) {
        return response.total; // total is returned in the "total" field of the response
    }
}
```

Both taken from the docs:
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.total

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/y6KdK/

Comment: In this schema the total tried this function with passing parameter static! eg return 4; Most seem that at no time he enters it. Already placed an alert to check the moment you walk in there and nothing.
read when the option was always wanting to run the ajax did not work because it was missing something option.success (JSON.parse(result.data)), I believe that within that success would go through some method had to pass the value of how many pages to be shown as the result.data brings a json and result.total server side, More unfortunately still not clear:(
But! Thanks for help you

Comment: I would like to help, but I simply do not understand your problem. You can return whatever you want from the `total` function; you can reference a property that is sent in the response, like "total" or another one, or you can just put a static value there, although I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you set the total to a static value, like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/y6KdK/4/), what doesn't work for you?

Comment: This worked perfectly! Now I do not understand why the project differs from the one you did now is that the read and use an ajax function in the ajax success: function (result) {option.success (result);}, this result is a json semenhante the your example is showing over 275 items :(

Comment: This time I managed to make it work properly! Thank you for your help and patience! ;)